# Zend_Rest_Controller not calling action

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, rest

I'm in the process of setting up a website using the Zend Framework, where it can either be called as an API or be used in a proper MVC setup to build a website on it as well.

I've setup a Zend_rest_route that checks the URI and determines what route to use.

To call the API we use:

```
http://api.domain.com/controller/action/id/1
```

and for the website we call

```
http://domain.com/controller/action/id/1
```

The idea is that you only need to create one controller containing all the actions that can be used for the website and API, minimizing the need to rewrite code.

I created a base controller that extends the Zend_Rest_Controller that is then extended by all the Controller in order to have the underlying power of the API.

The problem that I'm facing is that when I call an controller/action using the API it the action doesn't get called.

When I var_dump the request object I get the following:

```
Website - http://domain.com/guestbook/test/id/5 :

...
["_params":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    ["controller"]=>
    string(9) "guestbook"
    ["action"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["module"]=>
    string(7) "default"
  }
...
```

-

```
API - http://api.domain.com/guestbook/test/id/5 :
...
  ["_params":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    ["controller"]=>
    string(9) "guestbook"
    ["action"]=>
    string(3) "get"
    ["test"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["module"]=>
    string(7) "default"
  }
...
```

The website calls the correct action "test", but the API call the "get" action and then "test" becomes the first parameter.

How can I get it to call the correct action?

```
PHP CODE TO FOLLOW:
```

Router in Bootlstrap:

```
$this->bootstrap('frontController');
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($frontController);
$frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('default', $restRoute);
```

Base Constroller:

```
abstract class My_Controller_Base extends Zend_Rest_Controller
{

    public function getAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()
             ->setHttpResponseCode(200);
    }

    public function postAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()
             ->setHttpResponseCode(201);
    }

    public function putAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()
             ->setHttpResponseCode(200);
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()
             ->setHttpResponseCode(204);
    }

}
```

And finally my Guestbook Controller:

```
class GuestbookController extends My_Controller_Base
{
    private $mapper;
    private $model;

    public function init()
    {
       $this->mapper = new Application_Model_GuestbookMapper();
       $this->model = new Application_Model_Guestbook();
    }


    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->entries = $this->mapper->fetchAll();
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        $test = new Application_Model_Guestbook();
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 1);
        $this->view->entries = $this->mapper->find($id,$test);
        var_dump($this->view->entries);
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with RESTful services, but I don't think you can set an action.

```
Zend_Rest_Route Behavior Method     URI     Module_Controller::action
GET     /product/ratings/   Product_RatingsController::indexAction()
GET     /product/ratings/:id    Product_RatingsController::getAction()
POST    /product/ratings    Product_RatingsController::postAction()
PUT     /product/ratings/:id    Product_RatingsController::putAction()
DELETE  /product/ratings/:id    Product_RatingsController::deleteAction()
POST    /product/ratings/:id?_method=PUT    Product_RatingsController::putAction()
POST    /product/ratings/:id?_method=DELETE     Product_RatingsController::deleteAction()
```

After your Module_Controller only the next two values will be used as a key-value pair and the rest cut off. That's why you don't see the param 5 in the dump. To work with RESTful services you need to use:

```
http://api.domain.com/guestbook/id/5
```

If you need to make it deeper, insert a module:

```
http://api.domain.com/module/controller/id/5
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, after considering this and looking at the code again, we realized that the user of a proper, easy to use MVC structure is more important that having a fully restful API. So we'll just stick to the normal MVC, getting the data and displaying it a contextswitch.